# Getting "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady" when trying to use Django contrib User module

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-users, django-contrib

I'm using Django 3.2.  I want to start using the Django contrib user module, https://docs.djangopct.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/, but am having trouble importing the basic User class.  I tried this

```
davea$ venv/bin/python3
Python 3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:44:01) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import os
>>> os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "directory.settings")
'directory.settings'
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I'm unclear what "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet" means or how to resolve it.

Comment: Use `python manage.py shell` if you want a shell with the apps already loaded

Comment: Basically Django needs to be loaded to use it standalone https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage so you can rather use shell management command that does this for you as Iain proposed